# Swagger-Codegen - generate only specific files

Tags: typescript, spring-boot, maven, swagger-codegen

In my angular spring-boot maven project I'd like to generate .ts files from the java request and response classes. In the api spec there are many other files so I don't want to ignore all of them one by one, rather specify the ones I need to translate into typescript files.
How can I achieve this through the pom.xml settings of the swagger code generator?